# Django and Bootstrap modal form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, modal-dialog

I am currently building a site with a contact function. I build the site with Django and Bootstrap. For contacting the people behind the site the user clicks on a element in the top navigation bar called `Contact`. This elements open a Bootstrap modal. At the moment the modal works as expected and looks like that:

[image: Bootstrap modal for contacting]

The code is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="kontakt" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Contact us</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kontakt-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kontakt-name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kontakt-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="kontakt-email" placeholder="Email-Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kontakt-nachricht" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="kontakt-nachricht" rows="8"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because I would like to sent the data that is written by the user to the Django backend I wrote a form that is:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name    = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    email   = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

In order to offer this form to all templates (implemented in the base.html) I wrote a context preprocessor that works fine.

Is there a possibility to render the Django form to my desired html? I tried `django-bootstrap3` but this app does not render the label and the input in one row. When I replace the input fields with Django (without any third party application) the class `form-control` and the id is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried [django-crispy-forms](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-crispy-forms/)? In this module you can set template name to `bootstrap3`.

Comment: Do you want to render the form to your desired page or render one form to all pages with different attributes each time? And I don't understand what you meant by "id is wrong".

Comment: I would like to use this form in all my sites. It is implemented in my `base.html` and all other sites extend it. Therefore I wrote a preprocessor that makes the form available to every site of my website. And if I render the input fields with Django it uses other id's that do not match with the label tags.